# What is the fn.bind Error code for discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that gives you on the command, !role {pronoun}.  If the pronoun exists then it will give you the existing role, but if it doesn't exist it will give you the role already made.  Each time I run the command though I get an error that says "Type Error: fn.bind is not a function".  I have no clue why, if y'all could help me out that would be amazing.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
        var input = (message.content.substr(12))
        var roleName = (message.content.substr(12));
        var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == roleName);
        if(!role){
            if (message.member.roles.cache.find("name", "Member")){ 
            message.channel.sendMessage('Sorry you already have a pronoun');
            return;
            }
            else if (input === ""){
            message.channel.sendMessage('Please Enter a Valid Pronoun Name');
            return;
            }
            else{
            var pronounName = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member");
            message.member.guild.createRole({
                name: message.content.substr(12),
        }).then(function(role)
        {
            message.member.addRole(role);
            message.member.addRole(pronounName);
            message.channel.sendMessage('You have created the pronoun: ' + role);
        });
            }   
        }else{
            message.channel.sendMessage('That Pronoun Already Exists!');
            return;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by `message.member.roles.cache.find("name", "Member")`. The [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method accepts a function as its first argument (you provided a string) and the value to use as `this` as its second argument (you provided another string).

You could find a role by checking if the `name` property is equal to `"Member"`:

```js
message.member.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'Member')
```

PS: Chances are there are other errors in your code but `TypeError: fn.bind is not a function` can be solved by this.