# TypeError: fn.bind is not a function. Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have an error but I don't know how to fix it.
I tried to use it but I can't find any solution but I'm new in .js and I can't do anything.

```
    async run(client, message, username) { 
      
      let gRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find('814663161662799872', 'Zarejestrowany/a');

      let rMember = message.guild.cache.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));

      var username = message.content.split(" ")[1];
      
      if (message.member.roles.has(gRole.id)) {
        const Nadano = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Już się zarejestrowałeś/aś")
        .setColor(0x0EC0E7)
        .setTimestamp('')
        .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/814587842071101530/2b018bbe88c48b277a50145a404cdaea.png?size=512')
        .setDescription("**Jeśli chcesz zmienić konto otwórz ticket na: #｜- **")
        message.channel.send(Nadano);
        
      } else {
        let logindata = { 
          username: `${username}`,
          userID: `${message.member.id}`, 
          name: `${message.member.username}`
        };

        rMember.addRole(gRole.id);
        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './usersfile.json'), JSON.stringify(logindata));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack of the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fn.bind Error code for discord.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66298002/what-is-the-fn-bind-error-code-for-discord-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that version, `find` requires a function.

Try to get the role elements by ID using:

```
message.guild.roles.cache.get("ROLID");
```

Or by name using:

```
message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "ROLNAMEHERE");
```